# Multi-valued attributes synch from on premises AD

Tags: azure-active-directory

We are looking to sync a multi-value attribute from on-prem AD to Azure AD. I read an article in which it's mentioned, its not yet supported but i would like to confirm from the experts.

My questions are:

1) Do multi-valued attributes synch from on premises AD to Azure AD is supported?
2) In Azure AD Connect, in Directory Extensions, how do I know from the available attributes if the attribute is Single or Multi-Value?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) AD Connect supports synchronizing multi-valued attributes to AAD.

However, AAD doesn't support multi-valued attributes synchronized from on premises AD.

See this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/32622497-support-for-multi-valued-attributes-synchronized-f), Azure AD Team replied below:

> We are investigating what it would take to add support for multi-value attributes in Dynamic Groups to enable this and related scenarios.

2) Looks we could not check if the attribute is Single or Multi-Value in the `Directory Extensions`, we could just know which are valid candidates.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sync-feature-directory-extensions#customize-which-attributes-to-synchronize-with-azure-ad

[image]

[image]